# App rejected Guideline 2.5.4 - Performance - Software Requirements

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, info.plist

Im trying to publish my app to the App Store and im keep on getting the app rejected don't know what is the issue
please find the attached image for my info.plist file

[image]

Guideline 2.5.4 - Performance - Software Requirements

below is the reason why I got my app rejected.

Your app declares support for external-accessory in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but does not declare any external accessory protocols supported by your app. The external accessory background mode is intended for apps that communicate with hardware accessories through the External Accessory framework.

Next Steps

If your app is meant to work with external hardware, supported protocols must be included in the UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols key in your app's Info.plist file - and the hardware's PPID # should be provided in the Review Notes field of your app in App Store Connect. If your app is not meant to work with external hardware, it would be appropriate to remove the "external-accessory" value from the UIBackgroundModes key.

Additionally, your app must be authorized by MFi to use the desired hardware. If you are not yet in the MFi Program, you can enroll at MFi program.

Resources

- Learn more about our requirements for apps using background services in App Store Review Guideline 2.5.4.
- Review documentation for the UIBackgroundModes key.

iOS App 1.0App Version
Rejection Reasons:

2.5.4 Performance: Software Requirements

I tried everything still app keep on getting rejected from App Store. please help

Comment: Since apple say you have external accessory in your background modes and the info.plist you have shown does not have this background mode, it seems likely that the info.plist that is in your submitted bundle is not what you are showing here. Start by creating your app archive and then unzip it (it is just a zip file, change the extension from .ipa to .zip) and examine the info.plist inside. If it is indeed different from what is shown then you need to check your Xcode project to see where it is coming from.